# How to validate two form in one submit button in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am beginner in AngularJS. So I faced little bit confusion this language. Please check my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="productFormForm.$valid && submitProductForm()" novalidate="" name="productFormForm">
    <label for="from_id_dropdown">Templates</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="from_id_dropdown" id="from_id_dropdown" ng-model="formData.form_id" ng-change="getDropdownOptions(formData.form_id)" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in forms_dropdown.availableOptions" required="">
        <option value="">Select Template</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-show="productFormForm.$submitted || productFormForm.from_id_dropdown.$touched" class="">
        <span style="color:red;" ng-show="productFormForm.from_id_dropdown.$error.required">Template is required.</span>
    </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="attributeForm.$valid && submitForm()" novalidate="" name="attributeForm">
    <label class="tooltip-demo">Label</label>
    <input type="text" name="attribute_lebel" ng-model="attr_value.label" class="form-control" placeholder="Label Name" required="">
    <div ng-show="attributeForm.$submitted || attributeForm.attribute_lebel.$touched" class="">
        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="attributeForm.attribute_lebel.$error.required">Label is required.</span>
    </div>


    <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is two form `productFormForm` and `attributeForm` But one submit button which is 2nd form. I want to validate both form those fields are blank.

Comment: for this, you sshould be using ngMessages, so when you type or touch your inputs they'll display the message error

Comment: Is there a reason for 2 forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate both forms using js - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9bpajkt4/)

or in html add `<span>` after your button -

```
 <span ng-show="attributeForm.attribute_lebel.$error.required || productFormForm.from_id_dropdown.$error.required"> Form not valid</span>
```

Comment: You just disable the button. But I want to show error message while clicking in the submit button